# SAS Macro Not Running

Tags: macros, sas

I can't seem to figure out why my macro will not run more than once. The error i am getting is something like: "The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS release.  Inserting white space between a quoted string and the succeeding identifier is recommended".  I get it... i have a messed up quote somewhere.. but i cannot find it anywhere.. please help.   Here is code:

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist kill; run; quit;
libname tw '';
libname jrd   '';
ods results = off;
options varinitchk=error;
```

`proc sort data=tw.datset_name out=x0; 
  by inquiry_id quote_time_dt quote_time;
run;

data quotes;
  set x0; 
  by inquiry_id quote_time_dt quote_time;
  if first.inquiry_id;
  year =year(quote_time_dt);
  count =1;
run;

data transactions; 
  set dataset_name;
  year = year(execution_time_dt);
  count = 1;
run;

%let q1 = swap_product instr_desc;
%let q2 = package_type;
%let q3 = dealer;
%let q4 = recipient_company;

%let t1 = swap_product instr_desc;
%let t2 = on_sef;
%let t3 = package_ind package_type;
%let t4 = alloc_ind;
%let t5 = block_ind;
%let t6 = initiating_company;
%let t7 = dealer;
%let t8 = exec_platform;

%macro create(input, vars, output);
  proc summary data=&input. nway; 
    class &vars. year; 
    var count;
    output out=t1(drop=_:) sum()=;
  run;

  proc sort data=t1; 
    by &vars.; 
  run ;

  proc transpose data=t1 out=t2(drop=_name_); 
    by &vars.; 
    var count; id year; 
  run;

  proc summary data=t2 nway; 
    var _numeric_;
    output out=t2sums(drop=_:) sum()=;
  run;

  data &output.; 
    format &vars.; 
    set t2 t2sums;
    total = sum(of _numeric_);
    array p _character_;
    do over p;
      if p = '' then p = 'Total';
    end;
  run;
%mend; 

%create(quotes,&q1.,table1);
%create(quotes,&q2.,table2);
%create(quotes,&q3.,table3);
%create(quotes,&q4.,table4);

%create(trans,&t1.,table5);
%create(trans,&t2.,table6);
%create(trans,&t3.,table7);
%create(trans,&t4.,table8);
%create(trans,&t5.,table9);
%create(trans,&t6.,table10);
%create(trans,&t7.,table11;
%create(trans,&t8.,table12);`

Comment: Have you run it using an MPRINT option to help you see the generated code? Any insight there?

Comment: You have a missing `);` at `table11`. This unclosed macro is the cause of it not running past there, or any subsequent code. Also, not sure if your `array p _character_` needs to be `array p{*} _character_`. And you clear the `tw` libref at the start, and then try to access it later. It might help if you actually stated what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Restart SAS to clear your unbalanced quotes and try your code again.

Comment: @Tom Is there any other way to clear the quote imbalances, other than restarting SAS? The process becomes tedious when debugging lengthy macros (not the best thing to do, I know).

Comment: You can attempt to submit a [magic string](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/08/19/errors-that-cause-sas-to-freeze.html), which may help in some cases.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107414/whats-your-best-trick-to-break-out-of-an-unbalanced-quote-condition-in-base-sas

Comment: Thanks Chris J.  That was the issue.